# send notification to parent class from nested class in Zk when using mvvm

Tags: java, mvvm, zk, zul

```
class A{
  private List<B> list;
  // getter setter
  public class B{
    @command
    public void delete(){
       // remove itself from list
       // Now how to post event to event queue to update list on browser
    }  
  }
}
```

The `list` is bind in a zul page.
One way i found is to use `BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, this, "list");`
but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is the VM than the correct call is

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, A.this, "list");
```

In java you call the this pointer in a nested class with ParentClassName.this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what the question is, but I'll take a stab at answering it.

Since `B` is not static (must exist within the context of an instance of `A`), you can call `A.this.list` to access `list` from within `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, A.this, "list");
```

Reference:

http://fossies.org/dox/zk-src-6.5.3/classorg_1_1zkoss_1_1bind_1_1BindUtils.html#a0634db05f8a346fc6cdd6a2c57848879

Comment: there is no ViewModel property available on this

Comment: Tell me @user2410148  Without view model how bind this list in zul page .I think you don't  know about MVVM concept in zk.